# How resample dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem, when I resample dataframe index, the date change !!.

```
>>>dpvis=dpvi.Puissance.resample('10min').mean()


>>> dpvi.head()
                     Puissance
Date                          
2016-05-01 00:00:00          0
2016-05-01 00:05:00          0
2016-05-01 00:10:00          0
2016-05-01 00:15:00          0
2016-05-01 00:20:00          0


>>> dpvis.head()
Date
2015-06-14 00:00:00    0.0
2015-06-14 00:10:00    0.0
2015-06-14 00:20:00    0.0
2015-06-14 00:30:00    0.0
2015-06-14 00:40:00    0.0
Freq: 10T, Name: Puissance, dtype: float64


>>>
```

Comment: Why do you resample on the Puissance column?

Comment: it's mistake sorry. dpvis=dpvi.resample('10min').mean()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demonstration that `resample()` will work correctly with the data you've provided, assuming that your `dtypes` are correct. It's not exactly an answer to your problem, but it may serve as a sort of sanity check.

First, generate sample data for a two month period at `5min` intervals:

```
import pandas as pd

Date = pd.date_range("2016-05-01", "2016-07-01", freq="5min", name='Date')
Puissance = {'Puissance': np.zeros(len(Date), dtype=int)}
df = pd.DataFrame(Puissance, index=Date)

df.head()
                     Puissance
Date                          
2016-05-01 00:00:00          0
2016-05-01 00:05:00          0
2016-05-01 00:10:00          0
2016-05-01 00:15:00          0
2016-05-01 00:20:00          0

df.shape           # (17569, 1)
df.index.dtype     # datetime64[ns]
df.Puissance.dtype # int64
```

Now resample to `10min` intervals:

```
resampled = df.Puissance.resample('10min').mean()

resampled.shape # (8785,)
```

Note: `df.resample('10min').mean()` also gives the same results here.

```
resampled.head()
Date
2016-05-01 00:00:00    0
2016-05-01 00:10:00    0
2016-05-01 00:20:00    0
2016-05-01 00:30:00    0
2016-05-01 00:40:00    0
Freq: 10T, Name: Puissance, dtype: int64

resampled.tail()
Date
2016-06-30 23:20:00    0
2016-06-30 23:30:00    0
2016-06-30 23:40:00    0
2016-06-30 23:50:00    0
2016-07-01 00:00:00    0
Freq: 10T, Name: Puissance, dtype: int64
```

Resampling works as expected.
This suggests that there's an issue somewhere with your `dtype` declarations, or with the format of an observation that isn't shown in your `head()` output.

One clue may be that your `Puissance` values start out as integers (`0`), but are resampled as floats (`0.0`).  If all of your `Puissance` values are zero-valued integers, the `mean` output `dtype` will also be `int64`, as seen above.  (`mean()` will normally return `dtype` `float64` if the values being averaged are not all the same.)  Your example data may not be representative of the actual problem you're trying to solve - if so, consider updating your post with a more representative example.

Comment: it's ok, but I have alway same problem . It's a bug ? Post down